# Why does adding a grails Service unit test breaks controller unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-controller, grails-services

Using Grails version 2.4.2

I have controller unit tests that were passing successfully. 
As soon as I added a MyServiceSpec that tests a MyService some controller unit tests started failing.
If I comment out my MyServiceSpec tests they pass again. 
I have been able to narrow it down to something related to MimeType bean initialization.

If the MyServiceSpec runs then the MimeType printed using

```
MimeType.getConfiguredMimeTypes().each { MimeType mt ->
           println mt.name
       }
```

outputs

```
text/html
```

Without the MyServiceSpec it is

```
application/atom+xml
text/css
text/csv
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
text/html
application/xhtml+xml
text/javascript
application/json
text/json
multipart/form-data
application/rss+xml
text/plain
application/hal+json
application/hal+xml
text/xml
application/xml
```

Without the json mime type the responses are not rendered correctly and the tests fail. I did not see any detailed documentation on allowing or disallowing unit tests for a Service class.

Is it incorrect to have a Service level unit test? Should it be moved to integration test area? Related question is why does default MimeType configuration get wiped out for the other controller tests when  Service unit test is introduced?

Comment: Does your code do anything with MimeTypes? It will help to see your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your unit tests this way...

```
@Mock(MyService)
class MyControllerTests{

@Before
void setUp() {
    service = mockFor(MyService).createMock()
}

@Test
void test() {

    controller.myService = service
```

**mockFor(MyService).createMock()** will create the actual instance of the mock object, that's what you will pass to the controller **MyService** attribute.

Hope this helps. Thanks.